# Wordpress How to show first full post then others are titles only

Tags: wordpress

how do i show the first post in full then the other posts just titles.

I've managed to strip some php code that generates the_content so i can just have the title displayed. Now i want the first post to show in full except for the others.

thanks.

edit: currently i have this default code to just loop through each post and show the title.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></div>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've already tried and tell us where it doesn't work or where you are stuck. Note that you can also try to post on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i've already updated my post. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php $i+=1; ?>
 <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></div> 
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <?php if($i<2): the_excerpt(); ?>
...
```

Comment: and, if you want to use the content change 'the_excerpt()' for 'the_content()'

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this...

```
<?php

    $per_page=$paged<=1?9:10;

    $i=0;

    query_posts(array(

        'order' => 'DESC',

        'paged' => $paged,

        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,

    ) );        

    if (have_posts()) :

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    if ($paged<=1 && $i==0)

{ ?>

    <!-- Loop that displays first post -->

    <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></div>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_content()); ?>

<?php } else { ?>

    <!-- Loop that displays rest of the post -->

    <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></div>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


<?php } $i++; endwhile; ?>

    <?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries')) ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;')) ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The numbers at the top is  what is offsetting it. **$per_page=$paged<=1?9:10;**

First page shows latest post in first loop **'1'**, then the rest **'9'**, and then on the following pages it displays **'10'** = **<=1?9:10;**

Hope this helps.